# How to remove from list all successive equal elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to remove from list all successive equal elements ?

For example:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5]
```

should become `[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]`

```
old = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5]
result = []
for e in old:
   if len(result) == 0 or result[-1] != e:
       result.append(e)
```

I can do like this but is there shorter way in Python ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`itertools` has a function to group repeating items, `groupby`.

```
import itertools

[item for item, repeats in itertools.groupby([1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5])]
#>>> [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

`repeats` is an iterable that returns the section, such that if you stuck all of the `repeats`s together you'd get back the original iterable.